# html table of text inputs not displaying correctly when values added with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html table where the (`td`) cells contain text inputs (`<input type="text"/>`).  Everything is fine (users can type into the inputs OK), except when I `.append()` a row where an input cell has a value, when an extra margin appears to be added above the input, destroying the alignment of table rows (this happens in chrome and safari but firefox is OK).

```
$('.myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" value="product code 1"/></td>'+
     '<td><input type="text" disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>');
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the css.  Anyone encountered/solved this problem?

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in a jsfiddle and duplicate the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the html of the table?

Comment: Will do this eventually if the question remains unanswered.  I'm hoping someone will just know.

Comment: From your code there is nothing wrong with it. You have some underlying css that is doing something here...

Comment: But if this is true, then I'm triggering some css rule, only when the input has a value (assigned by js!).  I'm not doing this.  I've gone through the css rules for the value inputs and the non-value inputs and they seem the same.  Also, it works OK in firefox.

Comment: maybe you should be appending to something like `$('.myTable tbody')`. maybe ! without your html i can only guess

Comment: it works fine in chrome for me 
http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/W9EYb/

Comment: mmm...  your table only had 1 row.  My css is a bit involved.  Will see what I can do in jsfiddle when I get time...

Comment: OK, thanks @Shih-EnChou. I found the answer when playing in jsfiddle--started by removing my browser reset code... he he he!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maniacal laughter! OK, I got this!  I had the following css browser reset code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu,nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

removing the `vertical-align:baseline;` bit fixed the problem!  Alternatively, removing `tbody`, `tr` and `td` also worked.  Thanks heaps to people for trying to help.

Comment: I guess chrome and safari were trying to align the added text to the 'baseline' of the tr.  Interesting that this only occurred when adding values in js.